# Does Windows 7 Support Removing Disks from a Spanned Volume?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, dynamic-disk

I would like to use Spanned Volumes in Windows 7 to present a number of disks (or iSCSI LUNs) as a single volume. I like to maintain flexibility in my setups however.

Is it possible to remove a disk from a spanned volume in the future?

I can find documentation about [shrinking volumes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731842.aspx) but nothing about later removing one from a set.

Comment: I hadn't used a spanned volume in some time, but from what I recall, the isn't a way to unspan a volume.  Also, if you want to access the space of the drive/lun from within the C drive, depending on what you want to do, using mount points or junction points may do what you need.

Comment: I was going to use it for storing hd video, just a convenience method basically. I'll post the definitive answer to this, and possibly my alternative solution once I get my setup rolling.

Answer (score 1):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737048(WS.10).aspx

You cannot remove a disk from a spanned volume in the future without deleting the volume itself.

That being said, just because Microsoft doesn't officially support such an operation doesn't mean it isn't possible.

Comment: Can you expand or link to details on how such an operation would be done?

Comment: I would think it would be technically possible on Windows, but not a simple task.    There are products/file systems that I believe can do this, like Drobo's BeyondRAID